# Using walletconnect v2.0 with TRON network

Tags: javascript, tron, wallet-connect

As per TRON docs (https://developers.tron.network/docs/walletconnect-tron), its now possible to connect the TRON network with walletconnect v2.

Within the tron api @tronweb3/walletconnect-tron, these are the specifications to pass walletconect signer object at connection time.

```
requiredNamespaces: {
        tron: {
            chains: [chainId],
            methods: [WalletConnectMethods.signTransaction, WalletConnectMethods.signMessage],
            events: []
        }
    },
```

Where chainId for mainnet would be: "tron:0x2b6653dc", and methods: "tron_signTransaction" "tron_signMessage".

This in correlation to EIP155 Namespaces which are, and you can find in (https://docs.walletconnect.com/2.0/javascript/sign/dapp-usage)

```
requiredNamespaces: {
      eip155: {
        methods: [
          "eth_sendTransaction",
          "eth_signTransaction",
          "eth_sign",
          "personal_sign",
          "eth_signTypedData",
        ],
        chains: ["eip155:1"],
        events: ["chainChanged", "accountsChanged"],
      },
    },
```

Does anybody has succesfully use this new features? I'm trying with Trust Wallet.

Appreciate any help in this regard.

Connecting my wallet to the TRON network using walletconnect v2.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of BitKeep supports using WalletConnect to connect Tron Wallet.
Here is the demo: https://react-app.walletconnect.com/
The walletconnect repo has examples: https://github.com/WalletConnect/web-examples/tree/main/dapps